# class="thumbnail" in <a> tag not working in bootstrap 4

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, thumbnails

I have watched a bootstrap tutorial  [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2-tHexxFixA&list=PL6n9fhu94yhXd4xnk-j5FGhHjUv1LsF0V&index=7) in youtube. The tutor was using bootstrap 3**(I'm using bootstrap 4)**, when I used the .thumbnail class as he did, My anchor tag is not getting rendered as thumbnail. is there any alternative to render the contents inside anchor tag as thumbnail as he did?

```
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
        <a href="img/butterfly.jpg" class="thumbnail">
          <p>ButterFly</p>
          <img src="img/butterfly.jpg" />
        </a>
      </div>
```

Comment: Thumbnails were dropped entirely in v4.x for `a` tags and replaced by `card` components (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/migration/#panels-thumbnails-and-wells) - if you want to use thumbnails like in the video, you need to use v3.x

Answer (score 0):

Thumbnails were dropped entirely in v4.x for anchor (`a`) tags and replaced by `card` components (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/migration/#panels-thumbnails-and-wells) - if you want to use `thumbnail`s like in the video, you need to use v3.x

Alternatively, you can use Image Thumbnails, like:

`<img src="..." alt="..." class="img-thumbnail">`

See docs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/content/images/#image-thumbnails